# Suggest a word for teenish for my teen-ish fantasy

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, meaning-in-context, british-english, pejorative-language

> Hi Sita, got fascinated after reading your review of "All the light we
>   cannot see" and would like to add you as a friend. Your review seemed
>   totally original and written from heart. I would say that though your
>   language was foul and teen-ish I enjoyed every bit of it. Your name
>   suggests you are from India but your style of writing and flurrying
>   the F-words makes me guess otherwise.

Just sent a friend request to Sita on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com) but was dismayed when my Mac showed *teenish* as spell-error when I thought its a proper word with its meaning well conveyed. I would be delighted if the meaning of suggested word matches with what I want to convey in the quote above.

Comment: Adolescent may do the trick.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Adolescent signifies more like childish or juvenile behaviour, I am looking for something more pejorative.

Comment: How about _teeny-bopper_? May be dated, but is is mildly pejorative.

Comment: @Cascabel Hell no! teeny-bopper seems to bobbitise the whole context!! Please suggest something with suffix -ish.

Comment: Why on earth would you pay any attention to what your Mac tells you about English? It can't even read C without a translator.

Comment: @StoneyB I am not sure about your feelings towards Mac or Steve Jobs but certainly it has helped me with my English with its inbuilt Oxford dictionary to find instant word meanings and thesauruses. As a non-native English speaker what stuck me is the simplicity of the error. Teenish seems to perfectly convey its meaning and I cannot understand why its not included in the dictionary.

Comment: In an informal context such as your message, the suffix -ish is often added to words that would not otherwise be recognized with it.  In fact, it is even used on it's own to mean _more or less_ or _something like that_.  It would never do on, say, a resume or business letter, but in an informal message, it's fine.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Well you have fairly convinced me that adding the suffix -ish is okay in informal texts to mean more or less something similar. If you can elaborate your comment as an answer I would accept it. Plus is there a policy of avoiding adding -ish-words to the dictionary, or they add it only when it becomes popular?

Comment: To me, *adolescent* and *juvenile* seem more pejorative than *teenish*

Comment: You can add "ish" to just about anything. Vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an informal context such as your message, the suffix -ish is often added to words that would not otherwise be recognized with it. In fact, it is even used on it's own to mean more or less or something like that.

Dictionary.com has this definition:

> ***[-ish](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ish)***
>
> 1. a suffix used to form adjectives from nouns, with the sense of “belonging to” (*British; Danish; English; Spanish*); “after the manner of,” “having the characteristics of,” “like” (*babyish; girlish; mulish*); “addicted to,” “inclined or tending to” (*bookish; freakish*); “near or about” (*fiftyish; sevenish*).
> 2. a suffix used to form adjectives from other adjectives, with the sense of “somewhat,” “rather” (*oldish; reddish; sweetish*).

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ish) has more info and examples and [Slate has an article](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/06/09/ish_how_a_suffix_became_an_independent_word_even_though_it_s_not_in_all.html) about it:

> The canonical use of -ish is as a suffix meaning "approximately," as in bluish, tallish, sixish, or even hungry-ish. This is the definition—the only definition—that you'll find in Merriam-Webster ...
>
> For centuries now, -ish has been rather promiscuous in English, attaching to a wide variety of words and even phrases.

It would never do on, say, a resume or business letter, but in an informal message, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Would sophmoric work? There aren't many words specifically relating to the teenage years, and juvenile does have a fairly negative context.